# Motor controller - transistor taking up 3/4th of the voltage

Tags: transistors, h-bridge, motor-controller

I am trying to make a motor controller for a DC brushed motor. The design is fairly simple, see below - motor represented by inductor

[image: schematic]

The problem I am having is that if we imagine A to be HIGH and B to be LOW, the motor is not dropping 12V (or close to). If I use a multimeter to measure voltage between drain-source on Q5 I get about 8.4V, on Q8 I get close to 0V. The voltage drop across the motor I measured to be the remaining 3.6V.

Would anyone have an idea why my circuit is not operating as I had imagined, and if so, what improvements could I make?

Answer (score 3):

You're not turning Q5 on properly. It needs a certain Vgs to turn on fully. Measure Vgs on Q8 which works and arrange for the same Vgs on Q5. (Start by working out the source voltage on Q5 when it is fully on).

This usually means arranging for Q5 to be driven from a different signal (generated by a level shifter). Which means a supply voltage greater than 12V to power the gate drive.

Or using a different FET for Q5 (usually a PMOS with source connected to 12V, drain connected to load, and pulling the drive voltage down from 12V.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of problems here.

First, to turn the high side transistors on, the gate voltage would have to be higher than 12V. How high depends on your choice of transistor.

Second, what FETs are you using? Depending on their gate threshold spec, they may not be turning on all the way anyway.

A FET H bridge is best done with an H bridge driver IC. They have the bootstrapping for the high side transistors and gate drivers built in, and add the appropriate dead times to avoid shorting the power bus.

Answer (score 3):

You have two basic problems.

First, the top FETs should be P channel, not N channel.  That means a gate voltage below the source will turn them on.  This is necessary with your drive arrangement since the gate voltages will always be between ground and the supply.  This prevents the N channel FETs at top from turning on.

Second, you have to consider break before make.  Even if the top FETs were P channel, it is quite possible that there is a gate voltage where both FETs will be significantly on at the same time.  That will cause large current spikes, which is not good for the FETs and probably not for the power supply either.  If you drive each of the 4 gates separately, you can arrange for some *dead time* between turning off one of the transistors on a side before turning the other on.  Fortunately many microcontrollers are available with PWM outputs meant for exactly this application, including a programmable dead time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I will change the circuit to http://i.imgur.com/jLPqWyr.jpg, unfortunately I wont have the PMOS transistors before tomorrow so I can't tell if it would work. Would you say this circuit is better for motor controlling? 

Thanks for the warning - I am aware that due to charging/discharging of gates that there is a chance of short circuiting, and I will implement later so that there is in fact time for the gates to discharge. Right now I am only driving one input HIGH with the other LOW, so no shorting should occur.

Comment: @Martin: You should update your question with the new circuit.  I don't see the point to R9 and R10.  R3 and R8 are way too high.  The top FETs will turn off very slowly with such high values.